# Queueing animations in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#footer-nav-li li.aboutme-footer-li:first').click(function(){
         $(".about-me").animate({right: '332px'}, "fast", "swing");
         $(".portfolio").animate({right: '664px'}, "fast", "swing");
         $(".contactme").animate({right: '996px'}, "fast", "swing");
         $(".aboutme-container").animate({right: '-197px'}, "fast", "swing");
    });
});
```

All is fine but animation executes all at once, I'd like to delay the last one (with .aboutme-container) until the aboutme, portfolio and contact me is fully executed. I'm not getting it done right, I just hope someone will be able to help :)

Comment: You may find this helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370298/how-do-i-animate-in-jquery-without-stacking-callbacks

Comment: this is what I was looking for! Thanks!